# Is there any alternate way to use $lookup in a View which consists of Sharded collections

Tags: mongodb, sharding

MongoDB official documentation says that:

> Views are considered sharded if their underlying collection is
>   sharded. As such, you cannot specify a sharded view for the from field
>   in $lookup and $graphLookup operations.

I wonder that if I decide to use views and if I need sharding the collections in future, is there any way to manage this situation?